# Optimizing djangos latest query for huge set

Tags: django, postgresql, optimization

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, related_name='offers')
    # arbitrary information

class Odds(models.Model):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, related_name='odds')
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'time'

    # arbitrary information
```

I have a potentially huge set of `Offer`s where I need to get the `latest` `Odds` object. The query I am performing right now is the following

```
for m in Match.objects.all():
    odds = [o.odds.latest() for o in m.offers.all()]
```

The rest of the `Odds` objects connected to `Offer` are stored for historical purposes and should not be used in the computations that would follow.

The problem is that this computes one query for each `Offer` object and is a huge time and performance factor that I'm drastically trying to fix.

**TLDR;**
I want to get one `Odds` object for each `Offer`, using `ORDER BY time`.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefetch_related. it does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python, instead of many small queries from your code.

For Django 1.6 and earlier:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, related_name='offers')

    def latest_odds(self):
        return max(self.odds.all(), key=lambda odds: odds.time)
...

for m in Match.objects.all().prefetch_related('offers__odds'):
    odds = [o.latest_odds() for o in m.offers.all()]

---------
3 queries
```

In Django 1.7, there is a Prefetch() object that allows you to control the behaviour of prefetch_related:

```
for m in Match.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch("offers__odds", queryset=Odds.objects.order_by('time'))):
    odds = [o.odds.first() for o in m.offers.all()]

---------
3 queries
```

If `Odds` is really huge, you should look towards denormalization table